# How to handle SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission not being auto-granted on some pre-Marshmallow devices

Tags: android, android-overlay

I've been getting reports of some Xiaomi devices (e.g. Mi 2, running API level 21) not showing overlays.  My app targets API 23.

There are [several](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xiaomi-mi-3/help/link-bubble-playing-nice-t2857607) [posts](http://en.miui.com/thread-30931-1-1.html) out there regarding this.  It seems that MIUI devices do not enable this permission at install time (unlike other pre-Marshmallow devices).

Unfortunately, `Settings.canDrawOverlays()` only works on Android 23+.

1. What is the correct way to check whether this permission has not yet been enabled pre-Marshmallow?
2. Is there an Intent to take the user to the relevant MUIU settings page? Maybe: `new Intent("android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION", packageName)` but I have no means to test this.

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? I'm facing the similar issue. Some devices (Xiaomi, Meizu) don't grant "Draw over other app" by default.

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checking if you have the drawOverlays permission is safer using this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static boolean canDrawOverlayViews(Context con){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT< Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){return true;}
    try { 
        return Settings.canDrawOverlays(con); 
    }
    catch(NoSuchMethodError e){ 
        return canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection(con); 
    }
}


public static boolean canDrawOverlaysUsingReflection(Context context) {

    try {

        AppOpsManager manager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        Class clazz = AppOpsManager.class;
        Method dispatchMethod = clazz.getMethod("checkOp", new Class[] { int.class, int.class, String.class });
        //AppOpsManager.OP_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW = 24
        int mode = (Integer) dispatchMethod.invoke(manager, new Object[] { 24, Binder.getCallingUid(), context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() });

        return AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED == mode;

    } catch (Exception e) {  return false;  }

}
```

Custom ROMs can have altered the OS so that that Settings.canDrawOverlays() is not available. This happened to me with Xiaomi devices and the app crashed.

Requesting the permission:

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
public static void requestOverlayDrawPermission(Activity act, int requestCode){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + act.getPackageName()));
    act.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

}
```

Answer (score 22):

1) on pre-API 23, the permission is already given, because the user granted it upon install.

EDIT: it seems there is a bug on Android 6 (that will [**get fixed on 6.0.1**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196597)), that if the user has denied this permission , the app will crash with SecurityException. No idea how Google fixed it though.

2) This way:

```
public static void requestSystemAlertPermission(Activity context, Fragment fragment, int requestCode) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.M)
        return;
    final String packageName = context == null ? fragment.getActivity().getPackageName() : context.getPackageName();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    if (fragment != null)
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    else
        context.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

Then, in the onActivityResult, you can check if the permission is given or not, as such:

```
@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.M)
public static boolean isSystemAlertPermissionGranted(Context context) {
    final boolean result = VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.M || Settings.canDrawOverlays(context);
    return result;
}
```

---

EDIT: for the time being, if you publish an app to the Play Store, your app will be auto-granted with this permission. You can read about it [**here**](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/24/system-alert-window-now-more-hidden-than-ever.html). When I asked about it, I thought it was a part of Android itself, as I thought all we need is to target a high enough value for targetSdkVersion. What Google wrote to me ([**here**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222195)) is that they wanted to avoid issues on popular apps.

I suggest handling this permission correctly even if you will get it auto-granted.

Comment: Your answer is for the general case, which is not what this question is about. Some Xiaomi and Meizu devices do not work in this way.

Comment: @MarkCarter Well, this is how it should work. You should talk with them and ask them how they allow it to work otherwise.

Comment: right. The question is about how to apply a workaround for a situation that occurs on many devices - many of which may never receive an update no matter how successful people are in convincing xiaomi and meizu to patch the problem.

Comment: @MarkCarter OK. Sorry. You are correct. I don't know how it works there. You might be able to use try-catch for something that tries to put content on top for those cases. and also, for the intent itself, you could look at the log to see which intent is needed. If the activity is public, you might also be able to find it yourself (maybe try the "settings" app).

Comment: Any update for android 6.0.1 SecurityException bug? It still happens with targetSdk 25

Answer (score 5):

Here is the step by step how to handle this:

At first give below permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Or

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Then handle rest of the things using below code:

```
 public final static int REQUEST_CODE = 65635;

    public void checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
        /** check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                /** if not construct intent to request permission */
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                /** request permission via start activity for result */
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data) {
        /** check if received result code
         is equal our requested code for draw permission  */
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            // ** if so check once again if we have permission */
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                    // continue here - permission was granted
                    goYourActivity();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Just call `checkDrawOverlayPermission()` from your LauncherActivity or anywhere as your requirements.

When you execute the project you will see a window and asked for enabling the permission. After allowing permission you will be able to do anything about this.

Comment: You did not understand the question, so your answer does not help.

Answer (score 1):

For searching for while about the issue in Xiaomi, Meizu I have found this. It's working perfectly..

```
public static boolean isMiuiFloatWindowOpAllowed(@NonNull Context context) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (version >= 19) {
        return checkOp(context, OP_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW); //See AppOpsManager.OP_SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW=24 /*@hide/
    } else {
        return (context.getApplicationInfo().flags & 1<<27) == 1;
    }
}

public static boolean checkOp(Context context, int op, String packageName, int uid) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (version >= 19) {
        AppOpsManager manager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        try {
            return (AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED == (Integer) ReflectUtils.invokeMethod(manager, "checkOp", op, uid, packageName));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Flog.e("Below API 19 cannot invoke!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

> ReflectUtils.java

```
public static Object invokeMethod(@NonNull Object receiver, String methodName, Object... methodArgs) throws Exception {
Class<?>[] argsClass = null;
    if (methodArgs != null && methodArgs.length != 0) {
        int length = methodArgs.length;
        argsClass = new Class[length];
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            argsClass[i] = getBaseTypeClass(methodArgs[i].getClass());
        }
    }

    Method method = receiver.getClass().getMethod(methodName, argsClass);
    return method.invoke(receiver, methodArgs);
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382436/how-to-check-permission-system-alert-window-is-granted-on-android-lollipop)

Comment: @Manifest , how can detect if the device running miui  like Xiaomi, Meizu??

Comment: getBaseTypeClass don't compile, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can check permission like this:

```
boolean granted = activity.checkSelfPermission("android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```