# Android - How to allow/enable "Floating notifications" setting as default for App using code

Tags: android

I want to enable floating notification using Android Code.Normally users didn't know about the setting. so i need to enable this as default.

[image: App's Notification Setting]

Comment: did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 15):

*Bad news I'm afraid.*

As you probably are aware, this requires the permission [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW).

Since Android M google has [begun locking down](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/09/07/android-m-begins-locking-down-floating-apps-requires-users-to-grant-special-permission-to-draw-on-other-apps/) this permission to reduce clutter. What is a little unusual about this permission is it requires the user to go to an actual settings screen **The ordinary Android M permission flow does not work for this**. To quote the API:

> If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen

You use the Settings class to check if you already [have the permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#canDrawOverlays(android.content.Context)) and when you don't, you need to explain and direct the user to the relevant settings screen via [intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
context.startActivity(i);
```

This *should* only ever affect devices running 23+ as older devices should get the permission automatically, but don't rely on checking SDK_INT, rely instead on [canDrawOverlays](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#canDrawOverlays(android.content.Context)), as there are [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172390/how-to-handle-system-alert-window-permission-not-being-auto-granted-on-some-pre) for some pre-marshmallow devices

Comment: how is whatsapp doing it then?

Comment: i think WhatsApp, FB  is whitelisted from google for their notification

Answer (score 7):

I was also facing same issue and need to enable it from settings but after adding permission in manifest file it worked perfectly.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

Tested on version 9.

Comment: Thank you soo much @amit

Comment: adding this enables floating notification ? this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: It does yes. Make sure to double check your importance and vibrate settings when building the notification

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with that and found a way.
(In my case I'm using the [OneSignal React-Native SDK](https://github.com/OneSignal/react-native-onesignal))

The solution was to create a "category" (on the OneSignal console) that has the "urgent" importance :)

After that, when you send a push, you have to refer to the channel_id of this category.
Doc: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-notification-categories